# Interlacing Letter Objects Using Transparency Mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, transparency, clipping-mask

I'm interested in preserving the object integrity of the two letters in the image on the left.  However, I would like to interlace the letters in the same manner as the image on the right without using the knife tool (as I did on the right, which has left a line on the S just to the left of the V that I can't seem to get rid of).  I understand this can be done with transparency masks but I'm not sure how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can preserve the integrity of the letter alright but that does not necessarily provide the workflow you want. So in order to provide the actual functionality you want you need to share WHY you want to keep the integrity

Answer (score 1):

- Draw a path around the areas of the V you *want* to *show*.

You can draw 2 paths, select both paths, and then use `Object > Compound Path > Make` to create a compound path. This allows 2 or more paths to be treated as a single object.

- Select this new path (or compound path) and the V and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

This will *hide* anything in the selection *outside* the path/compound path you drew.

[Adobe has a help section](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html) regarding clipping masks if you get stuck.